# Better way to fecth data for EF

Tags: entity-framework, cdc

We have DB on which CDC is enabled. We had to find the data on basis of date supplied. So we had implemented the data fetch through db functions.

The code block is as follows:

```
private IQueryable<Letter> GetLetterQuery(DateTime? date = null)
    {
        IQueryable<Letter> dataSource = null;
        dataSource = DBContextHelper.Context.fnGetLetters(date);
        return dataSource;
    }
    public List<Letter> GetLetters(int attemptID, int cycle)
    {
        var dataSource = GetLetterQuery(DBContextHelper.CurrentDataVersion).Where(u => u.AttemptID == attemptID && u.Cycle == cycle).ToList();
        populateLettersChildEntities(dataSource, DBContextHelper.CurrentDataVersion);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private void populateLettersChildEntities(List<Letter> letters, DateTime? date = null)
    {
        letters.ForEach(u =>
            {
                u.Documents = DBContextHelper.Context.fnGetDocuments(date).Where(d => d.LetterID == u.ID).ToList();
                u.LetterDoctors = DBContextHelper.Context.fnGetLetterDoctor(date).Where(d => d.LetterID == u.ID).ToList();
                u.LetterFields = DBContextHelper.Context.fnGetLetterFields(date).Where(d => d.LetterID == u.ID).ToList();
                u.LetterDoctors.ForEach(d =>
                {
                    d.Doctor = DBContextHelper.Context.fnGetDoctors(date).FirstOrDefault(q => q.IDdoctor == d.DoctorID);
                    d.Letter = u;
                });
            });
    }
```

We had to fill the associated fields. Our problem is that it results in many db calls definitely. Is there any way to reduce the calls? AFAIK we are not able to use the include with such db calls.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code as *text*.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/47589 for more information.